# Como retornar todos os dados de uma consulta SQL fora da function?

Tags: php, funções

Eu tenho uma `function` que tem o objetivo de mostrar todos os resultados de uma consulta SQL ao banco de dados e preciso montar uma view com os dados dessa consulta.

A `function` é a seguinte:

```
function buscar_banner(){

    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_banners WHERE status = '1'";
    $exc = $pdo->query($sql);
    $cnt = $exc->rowCount();

    return $exc->fetch();                       <--- Não sei se uso este
    return $exc->fetchAll();                    <--- ou este ...

}

$dados = buscar_banner();
```

> TABELA

- **ID**
- **titulo**
- **frase1**
- **frase2**
- **imagem**
- **datacad**

Uma vez que tenho estes dados, não sei como retornar e qual estrutura usar. Se uso um `foreach` ou `while`. O que eu quero retornar é:

```
<p>Nome banner 1</p>
<p>Nome banner 2</p>
<p>Nome banner 3</p>
...
```

Consegui fazer o processo desde que se tenha somente um resultado, mas não consegui fazer a partir do momento que eu tenho que retornar um `loop` com os resultados encontrados.

Comment: Como está sua tabela tb_banners?

Comment: Meu projeto é procedural. Não tenho níveis técnicos para desenvolver tal em POO ainda. Agradeço sua resposta para me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$exc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` assim retornará toda a busca em forma de array associativo, onde os indices serão os nomes de suas colunas da tabela.

Depois um simples `foreach` em `$dados`:

```
foreach($dados as $row){
  echo '<p>'.$row['titulo'].'</p><br />'//escape de linha por precaução
}
```

**Referencias:**

**[Documentação PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**